# Override page.html template from an app

Tags: django, django-templates, mezzanine

Is it possible to override (or overextend) the page template (pages/page.html) in Mezzanine from an app? It seems like the view **mezzanine.pages.views.page** will always look for (and find) the template in the Mezzanine app.

I am trying to add a tracking code (Piwik) to all the pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

Django uses [multiple template loaders](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-TEMPLATE_LOADERS), and the one that Mezzanine will use is the "app" loader.

The only thing you need to do is to make sure that another template loader can find the "page.html" template before the "app" one.

The template loaders are called in the order defined in your settings (`TEMPLATE_LOADERS`).

Comment: An alternate solution (in the same vein as this) is to make sure that the app which contains the page.html you want to use is listed before mezzanine.pages in the INSTALLED_APPS in your project's settings.py.

Comment: The template I want to load is in the templates folder of the project root: templates/page.html, I also have a copy templates/pages/page.html . The filesystem loader is before the apps loader and TEMPLATE_DIRS = (os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "templates"),). Still not working ...
Any ideas?

Comment: Nevermind, it worked. I was testing on blog and the main page, but they utilize different templates. I could see how the overload worked once I created a new page. Thanks!